# Am I able to find individual returns from total weighted average of returns?

Tags: returns, asset-returns, return

As titled states… I am trying to figure out how to solve for individual return given average weighted total return and weights of individual returns?

For example:

2% = (r1 x 0.2) + (r2 x 0.5) + (r3 x 0.3)

What is r1, r2, and r3?

Comment: There are many solitions, for example r1=r2=r3=.2, or r1=1, r2=3, r3=-5, etc.  Are you looking for solutions that are subject to some constraint, or best satisfy some criteria?

Comment: @DimitriVulis that’s what I figured…. What are some examples of constraints that would help?

Answer (score 5):

You have one equation and three unknowns, as you found out this can’t work. You need at least as many independent equations as unknowns. I don’t see how you can make this idea work.